# ¿Por qué salen signos de interrogación en mi datalist?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un datalist que jala los valores de la ciudad de la base de datos, pero los acentos los muestra como signos de interrogación en rombos. ¿Alguna idea de cuál es el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], te comento que esto sería un problema de codificación de caracteres, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base/59510#59510

Answer (score 1):

Eso se debe a que la codificación en la que se está mostrando la información en la página y la codificación en la que se ha guardado el fichero no coinciden. Tienes dos soluciones:

1. Especificar la misma codificación en ambos casos, o
2. Escapar el caracter en concreto que lleva el acento.

Yo prefiero esta última opción porque me aseguro de que salga bien independientemente de la codificación que use y con qué programa se guarde el fichero. Además, si quieres poner algún acento o caracter contenido en el **UTF-8** dentro del otros componentes (como la etiqueta `title`), tendrás que elegir correctamente el escapado.

Por ejemplo, para el `datalist`, te valdrá el escapado con `& (&aacute; &ntilde; ...),` pero para el `title` tendrás que usar el escapado de **ASCII** o **UTF-8** `(/u00F3, /u00E1, ...)`